# How to push and present to UIViewController programmatically From a XIB in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

Im working on a project in swift 3.0 and I use the following mechanism to navigate from one UIViewController to another.

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MP3ViewController") as? MP3ViewController {
  viewController.mediaDetails = mp3Details
  if let navigator = navigationController {
      navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

However when I try the same mechanism in the XIB file it gives me an error

> **Error:** saying 'use of unresolved identifier navigationController'

**How can I create a navigationController instance here ?** bellow Ive shown the code of my XIB class that gives me an error

```
if let categoriesController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoriesViewController") as? CategoriesViewController {
  categoriesController.categoryName = trimmedCategortyNameText

  if let navigator = navigationController {
      navigator.pushViewController(categoriesController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that creates navigationController.

Comment: you need to call self.navigationController.pushViewController i guess. and make sure your current view controller is embedded in NavigationController.

Comment: the thing is the class type of XIB is UIView. bcz of that u cant declare as "self.navigationController". how would i solve this

Comment: @danu see my answer you can put the code inside your xib class file

Answer (score 2):

Consider this sample:

```
    let sampleVC = SampleViewController(nibName: "SampleViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sampleVC, animated: true)
```

### Edit

As per your requirement, you need to navigation from UIView to UIViewController.
You can achieve this in two way

- using delegate/callback
- using reference of `NavigationController`

I will be showing you the second way.

Take a variable of `UINavigationController` in AppDelegate

In **AppDelegate**

```
var navController : UINavigationController?
```

Then assign the navigation controller to this variable from where you are navigating to UIView. (Let's say from SampleViewController you are adding UIView, then write)

In **ViewController** (This is my MainVC)

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.navController = self.navigationController
```

Then in `UIView` class (**SampleView** in my case)

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate
    
    let sampleVC = SampleViewController(nibName: "SampleViewController", bundle: nil)

    appDelegate.navController?.pushViewController(sampleVC, animated: true)
```

I verified this.

Comment: would you be kind enough to amend it to my question n post the answer

Comment: @danu I think you need to replace UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MP3ViewController") as? MP3ViewController
with 

MP3ViewController(nibName: "SampleViewController", bundle: nil)

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: The thing is the class type of XIB is UIView. bcz of that u cant declare as "self.navigationController". how would i solve this

Comment: I don't think you can do push or pop operation to UIView class from ViewController.
If you want to push to a viewController from UIView then you can take help of referencing the navigationController in AppDelegate

Comment: @danu If you want to navigate to UIView from any ViewController, then you can add the view on the viewControllers view and add animation to make the effect of push animation. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: my requirement is to navigate from UIView class to a UIViewController. How would i do do this. a code snippet would much appreciate

Comment: @danu Check my edited answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

If you are using **storyboard**:

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MP3ViewController") as? MP3ViewController {
        viewController.mediaDetails = mp3Details
        if let navigator = self.navigationController {
            navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }else{
            let navigation  = UINavigationController(rootViewController:viewController)
            self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

**With Xib**

Initialize a instance of UIViewController like this:

```
   let  vc =  MP3ViewController(nibName:"MP3ViewController",bundle:Bundle.main)
   vc.mediaDetails = mp3Details
    if let navigator = self.navigationController {
        navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }else{
        let navigation  = UINavigationController(rootViewController:viewController)
        self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: are you seen this `mechanism in the XIB file`

Comment: no i dont se this. it says 'value of type ...View has no member navigationController

Comment: I have edited the answer to work with xib @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: the thing is the class type of XIB is UIView. bcz of that u cant declare as "self.navigationController". how would i solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same mechanism with Xib using Appdelegate

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let currentOrderVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVcId") as! YourVC

        var nav1 = UINavigationController()
        nav1.viewControllers = [currentOrderVC]

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav1
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```